# Converting text (json object?) in pandas cell to columns

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to pull data from a text values in a pandas DataFrame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['{58={1=4.5}, 50={1=4.0}, 42={1=3.5}, 62={1=4.75}, 54={1=4.25}, 46={1=3.75}}',
              '{a={1=15.0}, b={1=14.0}, c={1=13.0}, d={1=15.5}, e={1=14.5}, f={1=13.5}}',
              '{58={1=15.5}, 50={1=14.5}, 42={1=13.5}, 62={1=16.0}, 54={1=15.0}, 46={1=14.0}}'])
```

I have tried

```
df.apply(pd.Series)
pd.DataFrame(df.tolist(),index=df.index)
json_normalize(df)
```

But with no success.

I want to have new columns 50, 52, a, b c etc. And the values without the '1=' and I dont mind the NaNs.  How to do that? What is this format? 
Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Where did you get that list of strings from? Probably not a very helpful comment, but instead of trying to import this into a dataframe, I would probably try to get the strings in a different format instead

Comment: I got a csv with usual colums in addition to a column of this format. Unfortunately there is no possibililty to request a dirrerent format

Comment: @hashimov, can you show the code where you get that string before it was placed into a dataframe?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest as I said, I got those values in a CSV. Putting the whole csv here makes no sense. The example I provided exactly replicating the behavior or pandas whith this csv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With specific replacement to prepare a valid json string:

```
In [184]: new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda s: s.str.replace(r'(\w+)=\{1=([^}]+)\}', '"\\1":\\2'))[0].apply(pd.io
     ...: .json.loads).tolist())                                                                                     

In [185]: new_df                                                                                                     
Out[185]: 
     42     46    50     54    58     62     a     b     c     d     e     f
0  3.5   3.75   4.0   4.25   4.5   4.75  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
1 NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN     15.0  14.0  13.0  15.5  14.5  13.5
2  13.5  14.00  14.5  15.00  15.5  16.00 NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Very elegant way of doing it.

Comment: @calestini yours was also explicit and useful. I wish you have kept it. Thank you both!

Comment: @hashimov, rolled it back, but a lot to be gained here on this answer.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest this is a great solution, is there a way to preserve the order of the json?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way you can do it by changing strings in order to make your data look like a dictionary. There is probably a smarter way using `regex`, but that will depend on the assumptions of the entire data you have available.

My steps below are:

1. Change strings to transform your data into a `dict`-like structure
2. Use `literal_eval` to transform the `str` on a `dict`
3. Unfold the `df` into a new `dataframe`

```py
from ast import literal_eval

df[0] = df[0].str.replace('={1=',"':")\ # remove 1= and left inner dict sign {
            .str.replace('}, ',",'")\   # remove right inner dict sign }
            .str.replace('}}','}')\     # remove outmost extra }
            .str.replace('{',"{'")\     # add appropriate string sign to first value.
            .apply(literal_eval)        # read as a dict

pd.DataFrame(df[0].values.tolist())     # unfold as a new dataframe

Out[1]: 
     58    50    42     62     54     46     a     b     c     d     e     f
0   4.5   4.0   3.5   4.75   4.25   3.75   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  15.0  14.0  13.0  15.5  14.5  13.5
2  15.5  14.5  13.5  16.00  15.00  14.00   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```